# remover 0s from end of linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I want to remove all zeors occuring at the end of an linked list:
example

```
5->6->0->5->0->0
```

should became

```
5->6->0->5
```

I have tried this but its not working:

```
ListNode * N=L.getHead(),*t;
while(N!=NULL){
    if(N->getNext()->getData()==0){
        t=N;
        while(N!=NULL && N->getData()==0){
            N=N->getNext();
        }
        if(N==NULL)
            t->setNext(NULL);
    }else
    N=N->getNext();
}
```

**Notes:**

- L is an object of an class
- ListNode  is another class
- `getHead()` returns first node address
- next in class is private so cant access it directly.

Comment: Step 1: Find the last non-zero node.  Step 2: remove everything after that node.

Comment: I am implementing exactly same logic but there seems some problem

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ (already on line 3, how do you know getNext didn't return 0?)

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

1. Iterate the whole list, noting down the last node you found worth saving (init with the structure saving the list head).
2. Remove all following nodes.

That means two iterations, though none nested. O(#oldlist + #removed)

Your current approach cannot work.

Comment: No need to iterate again to the save position, just store a "next = null" there after saving the "next" value, and walk down the list to remove the zero elements.

Comment: I am implementing exactly same logic but there seems some problem,t is used to store add of node with 0

Comment: Then you are clearly not implementing THE SAME logic, but some other logic... ;)

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach it is to have a variable that holds the "last non-zero node", and then iterate over the list until you find the end. When you have found the end, you just pick out the "next" node from the "last non-zero" and set the "next" to NULL.

Then destroy the nodes that were left over at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing logic suggested by *Mats Petersson* it became much simpler

```
while(N->getNext()!=NULL){
        if(N->getData()!=0)
        t=N;
        N=N->getNext();
    }
    t->setNext(NULL);
```

Comment: Memory leak detected.

Comment: Yes, you will need a second loop to destroy the elements after `t`.

Comment: And I intentionally didn't write the code for this, since it's fairly simple, and I expect this is a learning exercise...